# CSS Animation looping in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have an animated element on a webpage that is to rotate once and then stop.

This works fine in chrome/ie but in firefox the loop is infinite...

```
-webkit-animation:.75s rotateLast ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation:.75s rotateLast ease;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation:.75s rotateLast ease;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```

Can anybody see what I may be doing wrong or has anybody experience this before?

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateFirst {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateLast {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1}
}

@keyframes rotateFirst {
    0% {transform:rotate(180deg);}
    100% {transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1}
}

@keyframes rotateLast {
    0% {transform:rotate(-180deg);}
    100% {transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateFirst {
    0% {transform:rotate(180deg);}
    100% {transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateLast {
    0% {transform:rotate(-180deg);}
    100% {transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
animation-iteration-count:1;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)

> The animation-iteration-count CSS property defines the number of times
>   an animation cycle should be played before stopping.

Comment: Thanks @SW4, It's still looping however?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle.net at all?